# Change terminal colour based on SSH session

Tags: command-line, ssh, themes, session

Is it possible to automatically change the color of the terminal based on which server I am connected to through SSH?

For instance, when I fire up the terminal it has the standard colors defined under my profile.
Then I ssh to ssh.example.com and the color changes to black & green instead. 
Then I exit the session and the color returns to the standard color theme.

I know that you could do this manually. But I'm looking for an automated way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can by changing the `PS1` value in `.bashrc` file on every hostname where you are connecting with `ssh`.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/316960/147044) to view how to costumize as you like the bash changing the `PS1` value.

[image: ssh colored]

On my machine (radu@Radu) I have in `.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[01;37m\] > '
```

On the hosted machine (radu@ubuntu) I have:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35;40m\]\u@ubuntu\[\033[00;40m\]:\[\033[01;34;40m\] \w\[\033[01;32;40m\] > '
```

Comment: How exactly did u manage to change the background color?

Comment: The '3x' codes change the foreground color.  the '4x' codes change the background color.  Notice that the hosted machine has '4x' codes, but the local does not. http://www.arwin.net/tech/bash.php

Comment: Is there a way to get the same result without changing anything on the remote box? We use VMs, and changes wouldn't be persisted for long...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xterm, this works great: https://github.com/fboender/sshbg

> ### How does it work?
>
> Black unix magic. Well, not really. Well, kinda...
>
> SSH lets you run a local command before the connection to the remote
> host is established. Some terminals allow you to set the background
> color with an escape sequence. It's possible to detect if the SSH
> command has exited from the locally executed command by polling the
> parent process PID in the background. Combine the three and presto!
> Background colors.
>
> sshbg matches (regex) entries in a configuration file against the
> provided hostname. That results in a profile name, which has a
> background color associated with it. See the "Config file" section at
> the bottom of this page for more info.
>
> ### Installation and usage
>
> Requirements:
>
> - Python v3.x+
> - A supported terminal
>
> Clone this repo:
>
> ```
> git clone git@github.com:fboender/sshbg.git
> cd sshbg
> ```
>
> Copy the `sshbg` script to some dir in your PATH, for example:
>
> ```
> sudo cp sshbg /usr/local/bin/
> ```
>
> Copy the `sshbg.conf` file to `~/.config/sshbg.conf`:
>
> ```
> cp sshbg.conf ~/.config/
> ```
>
> Enable the `LocalCommand` configuration setting in your SSH config.
> You can do this on a host-by-host basis, or with wildcards. To enable
> it for all hosts, make your SSH config look like this:
>
> ```
> $ cat ~/.ssh/config
> PermitLocalCommand yes
> Host *
>     LocalCommand sshbg "%n"
> ```