# How do I set the prompt to use two colors?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors, color-management

One thing I liked about Mint was that the terminal would usually show two colors: everything from the left to the `$` would be one color, and everything past the `$` would be another.

Is there a way to have this setup with Ubuntu?

Comment: FYI I found the /etc/bash.bashrc file from Mint 14 [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/d2K9YvbH). The very first and very last lines need to be removed, or you'll get an error. Also, it might be a good idea if the ~/.bash_aliases file is loaded, assuming such a file exsists.

Answer (score 23):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```sh
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

When `.bashrc` opens, locate and uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` (that is, remove the hash, so it no longer looks like: `#force_color_prompt=yes`).

Save the file, and open a new terminal window, and you should already see a change (the prompt should be **Light Green**, which is defined by **1;32**). You can then change any colour value you like; eg: **0;35 = Purple**.

To edit the colour values, locate the following section, and change the default values with some of the examples listed further down:

```sh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

You can check out [this Bash colour chart](http://www.arwin.net/tech/bash.php) for a full range of colour values, but here are a few basic ones you can play around with (note that “Light” isn’t what you might think – it actually means “bold”): **Black 0;30 – Dark Gray 1;30 – Blue 0;34 – Light Blue 1;34 – Green 0;32 – Light Green 1;32 – Cyan 0;36 – Light Cyan 1;36 – Red 0;31 – Light Red 1;31 – Purple 0;35 – Light Purple 1;35 – Brown 0;33 – Yellow 1;33 – Light Gray 0;37 – White 1;37**

For example, here is the line that I use it:

```sh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[01;37m\] > '
```

or, my girlfriend, use:

```sh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;36m\]\u\[\033[01;31m\]@\[\033[01;36m\]\h\[\033[01;33m\]:\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]\# '
```

Feel free experimenting by setting your prompt by changing the value of the PS1 environment variable in Terminal, as follows:

```sh
export PS1="...your values..."
```

or, just

```sh
PS1="...your values..."
```

Here is how my terminal look:

[image: terminal]

Source: http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/how-to-change-the-command-line-prompt-colour-in-the-ubuntulinux-terminal/

Comment: where does the flower photo come from?

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 5):

Simply modify `$PS1` in the shell startup files with the appropriate calls to `tput` in order to set and clear text attributes. See the `tput(1)` and `terminfo(5)` man pages for details.

```
export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 2)\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: "in the shell startup files"

Comment: Better [shell initialization files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)

Comment: Instead of `$(tput setaf 2)` and `$(tput sgr0)`, I'd recommend using the ANSI escape sequences directly: `\033[32m` and `\033[m`. The result is the same, but it doesn't require a call.

Answer (score 1):

This thing you are talking about is called [prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt). There are lots of options and scripts to modify your prompt using different colors and displaying any kind of additional information. A good start with some examples can be found within [jamie's collection](http://jamiedubs.com/ps1-collection-customize-your-bash-prompt) and [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) has some nice explanations for beginners. If you want to go more into detail have a look at this [comprehensive howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

(try it in a terminal first). Then, if you like it, you can put it somewhere in your `.bashrc` file.