# Change terminal profile based on ssh target

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.  I have a few terminal profiles that have different colors (e.g. login, cluster, and admin).  I would like it to automatically change the terminal profile to "login" when I start an SSH session to our login host, "cluster" when I ssh to our cluster, and "admin" when I go to our admin host.

Is it possible for the default Terminal to detect that I'm running something and change based on context?

If not, is is possible to change the profile by creating  aliases like:  `loginssh='$CHANGE_TERMINAL_COMMAND --profile=login && ssh login`
`clusterssh='$CHANGE_TERMINAL_COMMAND --profile=cluster && ssh cluster`

I see that it's possible to do this via the PS1 in my .bashrc from here: 
 [Change terminal colour based on SSH session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310498/change-terminal-colour-based-on-ssh-session), but I'd rather switch the profile than muck about with that.

Comment: Is this something I can accomplish with gsettings?  I don't want to change a specific value, I want to select an entirely different profile. 

I found an old solution using gconftool-2 here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660442/switch-gnome-terminal-profile-from-the-command-line

Comment: I also see that I can open up new windows/tabs by running `gnome-terminal --profile admin -- ssh admin` or the like, but I want to change the CURRENT window/tab, not open a new one.

Comment: The gconftool-2 (or gsettings, dconf) approach is conceptually broken, it changes the properties of _all_ the terminals using the given profile.

Comment: Search for OSC 4, 10, 11. They allow you to change the colors runtime.

Comment: I've filed https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/issues/183 for this feature request.